# ActiveWorkbook.Names.add seems to be incompatible with "Function"

Tags: vba, names

I have a problem with :

```
Function Create_Model(adress As range, name As String) As String

    Dim Msg As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.add "toto", "=Interface!$I$19"
    Create_Model=name
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
Resume Next

End Function
```

Indeed, if I run this, I get :

```
"Error #  1004 was generated by VBAProject
 Error Line: 0
 Application-defined or object-defined error"
```

It seems that the problem come from the use of "Function" because if I try to execute this with a "Sub", it's working.

Someone could please explain me why I can't do this with a "Function" and how I could replicate this function otherwise?

P.S : If I compile using Debug->Compile VBAProject. I don't get any message.

P.S.2 : This function aims to be used in excel formula.

P.S.3 : Argument used are : adress = J18:L20 and name = "Test". And finnaly, I would like replace "toto" by name and "=Interface!$I$19" by adress.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your code compile? Do a Debug -> Compile. What does your function return?

Comment: What arguments are you passing into the function? I just ran through the code with no error. Also, try going to tools>>options>>general and select "break on all errors". This will let you end route the error handler and see what's really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments below, I got to thinking, and realized that my original answer (see below) is perhaps more based in (my own!) best practice than being technically correct.

The main difference between a `Function` and a `Subroutine` is that a `Function` can return a value, while a `Subroutine` cannot.

I have heard of other issues in using `Function` rather than `Subroutine` but can't find a list right now. You have apparently found one, though! These (perhaps) rumors of issues, is why I tend to limit actions to `Subroutines`, and returning values to `Functions`.

After doing some digging, I've found the following resources that may help with further explanation of the difference between the two.

From Chip Pearson's site: a page called [Macros and Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/differen.htm)

From ExcelFunctions.net: a page called [Excel VBA Tutorial Part 4 - VBA Functions & Subroutines](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Functions-And-Subroutines.html)

Looks like I learned something today.

==ORIGINAL ANSWER==

Short answer and super high-level

`Functions` are typically not the best place to perform actions (on a worksheet, cell, file, create objects, etc). They are really good at returning values, and that is what they are designed for.

`Subs` or procedures are built for taking action.

I have never seen this particular issue, but have run into many things that trying to do them in a `Function` causes problems.

Comment: I understand your comment, but I really need to use the "Function", because I want that the user can be able to create a name easily just informing the range and the name. And the name in the output would be used for other functions which will use the range passing by this name.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I was under the impression that a function is equivalent to a Sub except it has a return value. A User-Defined Function is a special-case of a function that follows specific rules and can be utilised within an Excel formula. In a UDF, yes, you cannot do certain things that alter the state of Excel (some of the things you specified - although you most certainly can create objects (e.g. a Collection)). Out of genuine curiosity that I could well be wrong, do you have a link/example where a Function called in VBA executes differently to a Sub?

Comment: This answer is misleading, *unless specifically addressed to functions called from a worksheet as a UDF*. Otherwise, there's no fundamental difference in sub vs function outside of that case.